# Basic operations between univariateSplines

Tags: arrays, scipy, spline

I'm stuck with an idiotic problem, yet I can't seem to find any fast solution. I need to compute a difference between splines and that's not possibile within scipy.

So my question is: how to create an array containing the knots from my splines? I would love to set the range of interest and increments myself.

Comment: Question is unclear. I am voting to close this.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and provide the essential parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

To get internal knots of a `UnivariateSpline` object, use its `get_knots` method.

However, if go that route, it's usually more convenient to use the functional interface, `splrep` and `splev`.